# Windows store app "pauses" when minimized

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a windows store app. The app plays audio in MediaElement by passing a stream and does some activity on the screen with the progress of the audio. But when the app is minimized the audio "pauses" and the activity and when the app is maximized it resumes. When the app is minimized the "OnSuspending" event is also not triggeresd (I put break point on that function and it did not break).

How can I stop the app from getting "paused" when minimized.

Answer (score 5):

To keep your audio playing in the background you need to declare the Audio background task and handle the SystemMediaTransportControls buttons. This is described in detail on MSDN at [How to play audio in the background (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ841209(v=win.10).aspx)

Your OnSuspending event probably didn't get hit because apps don't suspend normally when being debugged. Visual Studio has toolbar buttons available when debugging to mimic suspend and resume. See [How to trigger suspend, resume, and background events in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh974425(v=vs.110).aspx)